# C++ Finding Index for Font temporarily added to System Font Table with AddFontResource() to use in Console

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application, custom-font

I am trying to temporarily install a font to use in the win32 console with

`int AddFontResource(LPCTSTR lpszFilename);`

and

`BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleFont(HANDLE hOutput, DWORD fontIndex)`

I got hold of this function from [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pavely/archive/2009/07/23/changing-console-fonts.aspx) site.

Although both functions seem to work fine I have no idea how to find the added font index to use with `SetConsoleFont`.

`AddFontResource` returns no index value or key to the temporary font.

Here is my relevant code:

```
#include "Level.h"
#include "ConsoleFont.h" //acquired from above mentioned site

#include <Windows.h>

 //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void init();
void cleanup();

int main()
{
   FileManager *pFileManager = new FileManager();     //unrelated
   Level *lvl1 = new Level("filename",pFileManager);  //unrelated


   ///TEMPORARY PLANNING
   // using add font resource. how can i get this fonts index value? 
   int err = AddFontResource(L"Files/gamefont.fnt");
   if (err == 0)
   {
       MessageBox(NULL,L"loading font failed",L"Error",0);
   }
   else
   {  
       wchar_t message[100];
       swprintf_s(message,100,L"AddFontResource returned: %d",err);
       MessageBox(NULL,LPTSTR(message),L"error",0);
   }
   SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE,0,0); 

   //acquiring handle to current active screen buffer 
   HANDLE tempHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
   if (tempHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
    MessageBox(NULL,L"Failed to aquire Screen Buffer handle",L"Error",0);
   }

       //I dont know what to set this to. this is the crux of the problem.
   DWORD  fontIndex = 1;
   if (FALSE == SetConsoleFont(tempHandle,fontIndex))
   {
       MessageBox(NULL,L"loading console font failed",L"Error",0);
   }

    //draws a house when in correct font
    std::cout<<"!!!!!!!!#\n"
         <<"!!!!!!!!!\n"
         <<"! !! !! !\n"
         <<"!!!!!!!!!\n"
         <<"! !! !! !\n"
         <<"!!!!!!!!!\n"
         <<"! !! !! !\n"
         <<"!!!!!!!!!\n"
         <<"! !! !! !#\n"
         <<"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"<<std::endl;

       ///PLANNING OVERS 


    bool quit = false;
    while(!quit)
    {
           //still to be implemented
    }



    err = RemoveFontResource(L"Files/gamefont.fnt");
    if (err==0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,L"removing font failed",L"Error",0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to go about finding my new font's index value or even if this is possible using my current method.

If someone knows or has a better method please help me out.
any help or hints are appreciated. It must possible to use a custom font in the win32 Console without fiddling with the registry. I'm sure of it :)

Comment: SetCurrentConsoleFontEx().  Big maybe.

Comment: Sorry Brother, I'm late I guess... This might work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/font-enumeration Please let me know If it worked for you! 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you entered the dark world on Win APIs. There is no documentation (or atleast I could never find it) for a console font table lookup. You can try the method "GetNumberOfConsoleFonts()" to see what is returned. I think the font at index 10 is Lucida Console. You'll have to play around a little. Also, this may not work for the OS version you have. Worked for me on XP. Never had to try on anything else. And honestly, never got it fully working on XP too.

For the registry,

Fonts registries are here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts
```

Console registries are here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console
```

If you end up modifying the registry, the changes may not be reflected immediately. You need to either restart the console or send a special WM_* message (sorry don't remember the name).

Will be great if you can find a solution/workaround :)

Comment: thanks for your help. ill delve a little deeper in and post a solution once I find it ;)

Comment: Never found a solution within the parameters of my question. I officially give up. If anyone finds themselves where I found myself, save yourself a bunch of time and use a framework that's applicable to your use case. With that said if anyone finds a way to do it I would love to know.

Answer (score 1):

```
   int err = AddFontResource(L"Files/gamefont.fnt");
   if (err == 0)
   {
       MessageBox(NULL,L"loading font failed",L"Error",0);
   }
   else
   {  
       wchar_t message[100];
       swprintf_s(message,100,L"AddFontResource returned: %d",err);
       MessageBox(NULL,LPTSTR(message),L"error",0);
   }
```

this is wrong AddFontResource returns the number of fonts loaded, so the code in the ELSE doesn't make sense.

Comment: maybe if you'd be a bit more constructive

Comment: I meant that the code inside the else seems to treat an error situation, while when the err integer is greater than 1 it means that AddFontResource actually loaded one font (so it tells that the operation went well)

Comment: sorry I didn't meant to sound angry

Comment: you didn't. But the more description you provide with your answer the easier it will be to understand / apply / and to learn from it

Comment: I agree with you that it doesn't make sense. I think I was trying to display how many fonts were loaded and forgot to modify the message box title / rename the var to something more appropriate. Its something I'll watch out for in the future to avoid confusing myself and others. thanks :)